# Bitcoins mysteriously transferred out of my wallet?

Tags: wallet, lost-bitcoins

I started mining bitcoins a few months ago, picked up a couple ASIC miners and have had my computer using them. I've been mining using Slush pool. I had my settings set to send bitcoins to my address when I reached 0.1 bitcoins.

I finally reached that yesterday, and Slush sent me my 0.1 (actually, it sent 0.1000341, because I was slightly above). The transaction can be seen as the second transaction on this page: https://blockchain.info/address/1LxLWPmzh3uMCmTwterHoFkrQagsFoF3Wm

Now, that was great, I now have 0.1 bitcoins! Then, when I got home from work today, I checked my bitcoin wallet and I noticed that it said I have 0 bitcoins! I checked the transactions, and there's a second one listed. The second one listed is for the exact amount I just received, with a transaction date/time of "28 Feb 2014 01:49", just under 8 hours after I received the bitcoins. (transaction listed at the top of the link posted above)

Does anyone know what happened? Did someone break into my wallet? Wouldn't they need my private key and my password to do that? Is there something else going on that I don't know about?

Comment: One possibility is that there's malware installed on your computer, in which case your key could be compromised. What OS are you running? Have you downloaded any untrusted software recently? Have you run any antivirus software?

Comment: The exact same thing happened today.
I was using Slush Pool as well. So I think somebody hacked into the slush pool account where they could see my wallet address and exactly how much money I made in the pool.

Answer (score 1):

> Did someone break into my wallet?

If you were using standard bitcoin client -- then yes. If some online wallet like blockchain.info -- anything could have happened.

> Wouldn't they need my private key and my password to do that?

The only thing needed to transfer coins is private key.